# TouchEvent in Blackberry 10

Tags: c++, touch-event, blackberry-10

As far as I know there are four types of Touch Type in Blackberry 10-

1. Down
2. Move
3. Up
4. Cancel

In slot `onTouch()` I check for these four type of events and do some of my task there. Like below:

```
if (event->isDown())
{
    // implementing my task
}
if (event->isUp())
{
    // implementing my task
}
if (event->isMove())
{
    // implementing my task
}
if (event->isCancel())
{
    // implementing my task
}
```

So, what is my problem? While executing some of my task in `isUp()` codeblock and at the same time I touch the screen. But I am not getting any `isDown()` event in my code while my `isUp()` is running. After finishing the task inside `isUp()` then I get the `isDown` event.

My target is to get `isDown()` event while I am touching my screen to stop execution inside `isUp()`.

How can I implement this into Blackberry 10?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

I recommand to read this interesting blog article, to understand how UI rendering thread discuss with the application thread:
http://devblog.blackberry.com/2012/09/cascades-custom-ui/

If your procces in "isUp" is this long, you have no other choice than doing it in a thread, and terminate the thread when "isDown" is called:
http://developer.blackberry.com/cascades/reference/qthread.html#terminate